# How is this granular, bubbly effect achieved?

Tags: sound-effects

What are some techniques that have been used to create the sounds at these timecodes?

The audio in question: https://soundcloud.com/rcoronado/voodoochild-open-fx-stem

Timecodes:

0'04 to 0'05

1'48

2'07 (beneath the thunder -- is this the same?)

I'm referring to that granular, electronic, bubbly sound. I hear it a lot but I have no idea where to start to achieve it. What are the techniques involved?

Comment: I'm not quite sure which bit you mean. I can't hear any "bubbles" at your time codes. There are some filter-sweep effects going on. Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best but it sounds different on different headphones.

Here is a demo

and also a flp file  https://www.mediafire.com/file/uvh9corg3akoiai/granularBubbly.flp/file since it is hard to get all things the same way.

Steps:

- Add an analog base (this should sound as if you touch a 3.5mm headphone jack cable that is connected to an amplifier)
- To make it sound even more like that you can use a formant filter
- Use some high pass filter, ring mod and bitcrusher and then a high pass filter again
- Distort it by e.g. Fruity Blood Overdrive or by making it a lot louder and then limiting it
- Decrease the Pitch by 20 hz
- Add a compressor, clipper and chorus
- Increase the heights in an equalizer and use another bit crusher and low pass